# why current frame number not equal to current page number?

Tags: latex, beamer

I use latex beamer to write ppt, export to pdf,

to display frame number, i add follow line in beamer header

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

After exporting to PDF,  pdf file has 11 pages, but frame number just 4.

As follow:

[image]

what i want is current frame number equal to current page number,

see the figuage,  the current frame should be 8/11( now current is 4/4, i think it's wrong), same as page number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve it.

Use follow, everything will be ok.

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
```

Comment: If this completely solved your problem, can you accept your answer?

Answer (score 1):

> what i want is current frame number equal to current page number

Do not use overlays.

LaTeX beamer distinguishes between frames and slides.
Each slide will be compiled to a separate page in your PDF.

A *frame* may consist of multiple *slides* (and thus pages).
This happens every time you use overlays, for instance as in this snipped:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item<2> Third item, shown only on the second slide of this frame
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

(Overlays are usually marked by commands with an additional `<[pagerange]>` argument.)

If your page numbers do not equal your frame numbers, you must have been using overlays.